# JQuery highlighting a row in an ajax loaded table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

A page contains two tables. First table is loaded together with the whole page and the second table is loaded afterwards with the help of ajax.
Both tables contain links in  each their row.
After clicking a link the corresponding table row (where link is) should be highlighted.

With the first table there are no problem. The following works ok:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#firstTable tr a').click(function (event) {               
            $('#firstTable tr').css("background-color", "white");
            $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "silver");
        });
    });
```

But there are problems with the second table. I try to use `.live()` method but with no success, it doesn't react on clicks:

```
function onLoad() {
              $('#secondTable tr a').live('click', function () {
                  highlChooseRow();
              });
          }

          function highlChooseRow() {
              $('#secondTable tr').css("background-color", "white");
              $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "silver");
          }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#firstTable tr a, #secondTable tr a').live('click', function (event) {               
        $(this).parent('table').find('tr').css("background-color", "white");
        $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "silver");
    });
});
```

should work without any problems. for cleanup you could also define some class '.higlightable-table' or something like that and use `$('.hightlightable-table a').live` ...